# nginx configuration to run node as domain.com and php in subfolder as domain.com/phptest

Tags: php, node.js, nginx

I am able to run node on port 8080 with pointing it to domain.com but I want to run php alongside of it.

Sample configuration is as below:

```
proxy_buffering on;
proxy_buffer_size 1k;
proxy_buffers 24 4k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;

server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
location / {

         proxy_pass  http://domain.com:8080;
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

         location ~* \.(html|css|jpg|gif|ico|js)$ {
                proxy_cache          cache;
                proxy_cache_key      $host$uri$is_args$args;
                proxy_cache_valid    200 301 302 30m;
                expires              30m;
                proxy_pass  http://domain.com:8080;
         }
    }
}
```

Now I want to run domain.com/php as php server so any request which has domain.com/php will process php and others will work on node. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes.. you simply create a new Location and forward it to FPM (php parser that works with nginx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 server {
 listen 80;
 server_name www.domain.com;
 root /var/www/html/testphp/api;
 location / {
 proxy_pass  http://www.domain.com:8080;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
 location ~* \.(html|css|jpg|gif|ico|js)$ {
    proxy_cache          cache;
    proxy_cache_key      $host$uri$is_args$args;
    proxy_cache_valid    200 301 302 30m;
    expires              30m;
    proxy_pass  http://www.domain.com:8080;
    }
}

location  /api/ {
    alias /var/www/html/testphp/api/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /api/index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        }
    }
}
```